Expected height of a binary tree with probabilistic leaf additions
I'm trying to compute the expected height of a binary tree where the leaves are added probabilistically.
Here’s how the process works:

The root node(level 0) is added with a probability of $1$.
Each node at level 1 is added with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$​​.
Each node at level 2 is added with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$​​, and so on.
More generally, a node at level n is added with a probability of $\frac{1}{2^n}$​.

This process continues until no more leaves are added, and the tree is finalized at that point. Let $h$ represent the height of this tree. I would like to know how to calculate the expected value of $h$.

I have confirmed that the expected value $E(h)$ is greater than $0.75$ and less than $3$.

$E(h) = 1 \cdot P(h = 1) + 2 \cdot P(h = 2) + 3 \cdot P(h = 3) + \dots $
$  = P(h \geq 1) +  P(h  \geq  2) +  P(h  \geq  3) + \dots > P(h \geq 1)=\frac{3}{4} $
$ \frac{P(h \geq n+1)}{P(h \geq n)} < \left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)^{2^{n+1}} \right) < \frac{3}{4} $
$E(h) = P(h \geq 1) +  P(h  \geq  2) +  P(h  \geq  3) + \dots < \frac{3}{4} + (\frac{3}{4})^2 + (\frac{3}{4})^3 + \dots = 3 $


Is it possibile to have one node at level 1 and four nodes at level 2?

It is not possible. The binary tree in this problem is a connected graph.

You might have some luck looking at literature on "inhomogenous site percolation" — I couldn't find your exact formulation but this is a particular type of that problem
